# error while installing cassandra from datastax in windows

Tags: cassandra, installation, nosql

I have downloaded msi installer from planetcassandra.org/cassandra.
I opened command prompt a administrator after running throw setup wizard.

```
C:\>net start DataStax_DDC_Server
The requested service has already been started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2182.

C:\>%CASSANDRA_HOME%\bin\nodetool status
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `%CASSANDRA_HOME%` path in the environment variable probably has a space in it (i.e. it's something like `C:\Program Files\ ...`). Try executing it with quotes around it:

```
C:\>"%CASSANDRA_HOME%\bin\nodetool status"
```

Comment: dear luke, it did't help ' '""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. '

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, which was caused by incorrectly setting my JAVA_HOME variable on "cassandra.bat" and "notetool.bat". Both files can be found under the %CASSANDRA_HOME%/bin directory.

Wrong:

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191"
```

Correct:

```
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191"
```

Put the correct line on the beginning of both .bat files and you should be fine.