# Cassandra executable not recognized in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, cassandra, command-prompt, cassandra-4.0

I'm trying to download and install Cassandra on Windows 10 by [downloading and extracting the tar file](https://cassandra.apache.org/download/). I have made sure to initialize new environment variables `CASSANDRA_HOME` and I have also updated the `PATH` variable to include the `bin` subdirectory (you can see it as the last entry in `%PATH%`):

```sh
C:\Users\jason>echo %CASSANDRA_HOME%
C:\apache-cassandra\

C:\Users\jason>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk11.0.9_12\bin;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\jason\code\aspectj1.9\bin;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Tools\100\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\mongosh\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\apache-cassandra\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3\bin;;C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.3\bin;;C:\Users\jason\code\aspectj1.9\bin;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Tools\100\bin;C:\Users\jason\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\mongosh\;C:\apache-cassandra\bin;

C:\Users\jason>cd %CASSANDRA_HOME%/bin


C:\apache-cassandra\bin>ls
cassandra        cqlsh     debug-cql  sstableloader  sstableupgrade  sstableverify
cassandra.in.sh  cqlsh.py  nodetool   sstablescrub   sstableutil     stop-server

C:\apache-cassandra\bin>cassandra
'cassandra' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\apache-cassandra\bin>cassandra.bat
'cassandra.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\apache-cassandra\bin>./cassandra
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\apache-cassandra\bin>./cassandra.bat
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Updating **both** user **and** system environment variables.
2. Trying through **both** cmd **and** Powershell.
3. Trying **both** as a regular user **and** an administrator.
4. Followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601570/error-while-installing-cassandra-from-datastax-in-windows)'s advice, where the accepted answer seems to imply that whitespace in the directory path can cause issues; there is no whitespace in my directory path.

The only progress that I've had is through powershell, where just running `cassandra` from anywhere in the system prompts me to select a program to open the executable, but from there on out I'm stuck:

[image: Open Cassandra with an Application]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? The fact that powershell can "see" the `cassandra` executable from anywhere in my directory tree makes me think that there are no problems with `PATH`. But I'm not sure what could be going wrong :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So `cassandra` is a bash script file; no surprise that doesn't run on Windows.
I also don't see `cassandra.bat` or `cassandra.ps1` in your `ls` directory output.

That last point tells me that you have downloaded the release candidate for Apache Cassandra 4.0.  Windows support was removed as of Cassandra 4.0, thus the *.bat and *.ps1 files are now gone.

If you need to run on Windows you have two options:

- You can download Apache Cassandra 3.x and run that natively on Windows.
- You can use the WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux) to run Cassandra 4.0.

Comment: Ah, indeed, now I've made some progress. Question for you: does Cassandra still not support Java 11? If so, are you perhaps aware of a way for me to make Cassandra point to JDK 8 instead of my default, which is Java 11 with the Coretto JDK?

Comment: @Jason Cassandra 4 does support Java 11.  Double check the jvm options file(s) and cassandra-env.bat to ensure which Java options are being set.

Answer (score 1):

Due to lack of maintenance and testing, Cassandra 4.0 and its further versions will **no longer be supported on WINDOWS**
Click [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171) to check.

If you still want to use Cassandra, opt anything out of these:

1> Deploy Cassandra in a VM using software like VirtualBox

2> Deploy Cassandra using Docker [link](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html)

3> Deploy k8ssandra.io [link](https://k8ssandra.io)